# Could not find parameter robot_description on parameter server

Tags: ros, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello
I'm ros beginner
I' m creating hand model in gazebo ros kinetic
I follow robotigniteacademy control course but I would like to try those on my own env
When  I'm trying to launch my model "roslaunch rrbot_control rrbot_control.launch" I can see [ERROR] Could not find parameter robot_description on parameter server
Everythin I need on this moment is move once of my joints
I need move any joint by terminal

Here is my project:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YjJ67zBniAlxsHNc3l2IEbhzTBs_sWgw

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19785/could-not-find-parameter-robot_description-on-parameter-server/) by [pawlas](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5692/pawlas/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-06-21

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-06-22**:
The right location to ask this question would be here: https://answers.ros.org/questions/

When i download and open the rar file it appears to be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So this is a guessing game, but in my experience the robot's controller needs the description of the robot to work.
I would suggest to look for a description.launch file or if you don't have it a description package for your model.

Loading a description in a launch file looks normally like this:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find robot_description)/robots/robot.urdf.xacro" />
```

---

Originally posted by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) with karma: 350 on 2018-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0